# Git - allowing write access

Tags: git

Setting up a git server where several users will be able to commit changes.

Lots of the documentation for this suggests giving them write-access to the repository and using SSH to do access-control.  e.g. http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-2.html suggests this even for hundreds of users.  Gitosis seems to continue the same approach, allowing SSH write access to the repository.

So my question is:

What's to stop someone `ssh server "rm -r /home/git/the_repository"`?

Is it really the case that in a typical installation, people with commit rights to a shared repository get enough filesystem access to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way to accomplish what you're looking to achieve is via [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which allows you as a repo admin to define relatively fine grained access rules.

gitolite identifies users by ssh keys so the users do not even have to have shell access to the server.

The [gitolite documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) is in my experience quite good.

Answer (score 0):

You should not allow the users *shell* access to the repository machine.

If you're going to be doing access control this way, the users' runnable commands should be restricted to `git`.

However, this won't stop them from doing other nasty things like pushing empty refs for each of your branches. If you don't trust the people who will be using the central repository, you need a finer-grained permissions system.

I would recommend [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) for this purpose. Even if you don't use it for code reviews, it still provides a management and permissions system around git.

Another option is to do pushing over HTTP instead of SSH; the HTTP servers provide additional restrictions you can set to avoid mischief.